Chromedriver Giving Permission and Timeout Error
I’ve downloaded the latest version of chromedriver for Chrome version 125.0.6422.61 (64-bit). I have the file in my directory and the path (C:\Users\USER PC\Documents\Flatiron\Web_Scraping) in the system environment but when I run this line in my script
    # Initializing the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()    
    # Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/USER PC/Documents/Flatiron/Web_Scraping", options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)

I get a permission error
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 2
      1 #This line will open a new chrome window and start the scraping.
----> 2 df = get_jobs("data scientist", 5, False)
      3 df

Cell In[31], line 13, in get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose)
      6 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
      8 #Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
      9 #options.add_argument('headless')
     10 
     11 #Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
---> 13 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/USER PC/Documents/Flatiron/Web_Scraping", options=options)
     14 driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)      
…
WebDriverException: Message: 'Web_Scraping' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I’ve changed the executable path and set a timeout value for page load as shown below
    # Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/USER PC/Documents/Flatiron/Web_Scraping/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
  
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)  # Set the timeout value for page load
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Set implicit wait time for finding elements

This returns this value error
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000001E756FC01F0>, but it must be an int, float or None.

What do I need to do to fix both the permission and timeout error at once?
